# How to underline whole heading divided into two lines

Tags: html, css

I was trying to underline my whole heading (h1), which is divided into two lines like this:

[image]

And I've done it successfully but didn't quite understand the logic behind it, i.e. when I apply this CSS, it didn't work:

CSS:

```
.main h1 {
  font-size: 65px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1A77FF;
}
```

Whereas, when I added span tag it worked for me

CSS:

```
.main h1 span {
  font-size: 65px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #1A77FF;
}
```

Can anyone please explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: add your html code.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

Any heading tag (like an `h1`) is a *block level* element so any border applies to the *block* as a whole rather than the text inside.

A span is an *inline* element and is only as wide as the content (with certain constraints). So the bottom border only applies to the span content *even when the line breaks*.

[**Mozilla.org (Understanding the inline box model)**](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/)

> Inline boxes are laid out horizontally in a box called a "line box":
>
> If there isn’t enough horizontal space to fit all elements into a single line (or the line is forcibly broken), another line box is created under the first one. **A single inline element may then be split across lines**
>
> When an inline box is split across more than one line, it’s still logically a single box. This means that any horizontal padding, **border**, or margin is only applied to the start of the first line occupied by the box, and the end of the last line.

```css
H1.block {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
H1 SPAN {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="block">BLOCK FORMAT</h1>

<h1><span>INLINE <br/> FORMAT</span></h1>
```

Comment: Very well and precise explanation. Thank you! :) @Pualie_D

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` is a block level element whereas `<span>` is an inline element.
When you use `<div>`, it wraps the text in a complete block as follows. So, border property is applied to that whole block.
[image: div tag]

And when you use `<span>`, it wraps the content line by line. So, when border property is added, it is shown under each line.
[image: span tag]