# Underlining headings for multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a heading with a nice underline. Not an actual CSS underline, but an underline partly overlaps my headings.

My code works correct for single line headings, but I am using this for a CMS, so it is possible that the headings become longer (multi-line). This is where I run into problems.

I understand that this is because the line gets inserted ::after the content, but I don't know if there is anything available to do it per line.

**Code example**

The code below shows two headings. As you can see, the correct underline works for one line only.
Is there a solution on how to get the underline for multi-lines instead of sticking it under the complete block?

```css
h1{
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

h1::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;

    z-index: -1;

    opacity: 60%;
    bottom: 0.1em;
    height: 0.25em;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Just a heading</h1>
<br>
<br>
<h1>A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very example long heading</h1>
```

Comment: Are you able to use a span as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696914/how-to-underline-whole-heading-divided-into-two-lines?

Comment: Nope, I tried it, but my headings are all block line elements. It's not possible to add spans in due to the size of the project. I do appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inverted `box-shadow` instead.

Like so -

```css
h1{
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px #fff, inset 0 -12px lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Just a heading</h1>
<br>
<br>
<h1>A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very example long heading</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Working with inverted/ negative values always throws me off.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```css
h1{
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: underline lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Just a heading</h1>
<br>
<br>
<h1>A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very example long heading</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It was not what I was exactly looking for, because this doesn't have the same styling as my initial design. But I appreciate the effort and will update my question to make it more clear.